# How to get new page source after navigating Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am facing an issue.
I navigate on the page via Selenium Chrome. I have timeouts and WebDriverWait as I need a full page to get JSON out of it.
Then I click the navigation button with

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

as normal click never worked.
And it is navigating OK, I see Selenium is surfing normally. No problem.
But the `driver.page_source` remains for the first page that I got via 'get' method

All timeouts are the same as for the first page. And I see those new pages normally, but the page_source never updates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can you be so sure that you _have timeouts and WebDriverWait as I need a full page to get JSON out of it_?

Comment: Because first page works fine and it took some time to adjust timeouts and WebDriverWait to make sure JSON loads completely

Comment: The problem point was that I was getting the same values as many times as many pages there were. After every click Selenium was giving me the same first source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After navigating to the new Page, you need to get the current URL by:

```
url = driver.current_url()
```

and then:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.getPageSource()
```

Comment: Thank you. For python it would be url = driver.current_url. It worked! Is there any other way, alternative? Because after 'get' new url page a little bit changes. Which is not exactly what I want

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks for the correction. What do you mean by it "changes a little bit" and when does this change happen?

Comment: It changes right upon loading. Driver is going on direct link in pagination and (I have no idea why) the search list changes a bit. It is like getting duplicated values from previous page. It is like there was 150 items found and each time after direct link it is getting 151, 154 , etc. All those are duplicates. No problem to eliminate them, but I feel like site protection might spot me because of direct link usage

Comment: I didn't know about this 'current_url', must have skipped while reading docs, thanks again. I was trying refreshing, searching elements, timeouts, everything to make the page "arrive" to selenium. I tried executing JS to get InnerHtml, but it was returning file without JSON and selenium tools to get InnerHtml again were returning the same first page, Nothing worked. For now only your approach is working and I and wondering if there is another one,

Comment: That seems like a loading issue to me. So i would highly recommend to let you programm sleep for a few seconds after getting to a new page so it can load propably. Getting the current URL with current_url() is the only approach I know.